# When using a Tensorflow Dataset from_tensor_slices(), is it possible to NOT load a new batch every train step?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to train for a few steps on the same batch since I want to give the CPU time to load the next batch. I am using reinitializable iterators and `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.range(n_train)))` and then using .map() to get my dataset by index. I want to run at least as many train steps on the batch as takes to load the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to repeat each datapoint `n` times right? The following should achieve that.

```
n_train = 10
n_repeat = 5
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.range(n_train))).interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x).repeat(n_repeat), block_length=n_repeat)
diter =  ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
elem = diter.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for _ in range(n_train*n_repeat):
    print(sess.run(elem))
```